# .append creates nan values for new added row and saves the values on new indexes. Why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have this data set:

```
inner_watt = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('input/0.7mm/0.7inner-100watt.csv')[' Current-A'])

Current-A
2.3309
2.3309
2.3309
2.3309
2.3309
2.3309
2.3309
2.3309
```

Now i slice the first 4 entries/samples and take a transpoose of them to convert into single row then append to a new empty data frame like;

```
formatted_inner_watt = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(4))
formatted_inner_watt = formatted_inner_watt.append(inner_watt[0:4].T, ignore_index=True)
```

The results are initially good;

```
0   2.3309,2.3309,2.3309,2.3309
```

However when i again try to append the next 4 entries it does something like this;

```
formatted_inner_watt = formatted_inner_watt.append(inner_watt[4:8].T, ignore_index=True)
0   2.3309,2.3309,2.3309,2.3309,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1   NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,2.3309,2.3309,2.3309,2.3309
```

WHY ?

Comment: The problem is with the column names. Check your column names after first append and then after the second append.

Comment: the columns are 0 1 2 3 of the empty data frame to which im appending

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd slice `inner_watt[4:8].T` contains another sequential columns (`4 5 6 7`), which differs from the 1st slice. So the column labels need to be aligned.

But, actually `pd.append` is deprecated, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) instead:

```
columns=range(4)
pd.concat([inner_watt[0:4].T, inner_watt[4:8].T.set_axis(columns, axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
        0       1       2       3
0  2.3309  2.3309  2.3309  2.3309
1  2.3309  2.3309  2.3309  2.3309
```